# How to correctly order an ArrayList<String> containing Strings and numbers?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I am currently trying to order an `ArrayList` of `String` elements (called `myarraylist`) according to the numbers found after the word "Item". Here is a snippet of what is in `myarraylist`:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
...
Item 9
Item 10
```

I would like to order `myarraylist` to the following order:

```
Item 10
Item 9
Item 8
...
Item 3
Item 2
Item 1
```

So far, this is what I have tried:

```
    Collections.sort(myarraylist, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    Collections.reverse(myarraylist);
```

However, this orders the `myarraylist` in the following order

```
Item 9
Item 8
...
Item 3
Item 2
Item 10
Item 1
```

As you can see, `Item 10` is out of place, because it reads "10" by its first number, "1". Does anyone know how to appropriately order `myarraylist` in reverse numerical order?

Comment: Same scenario in this but with times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818064/how-to-sort-a-string-collection-that-contains-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the default String `Comparator` uses [**lexicographical** order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) -- i.e. character by character, as in a dictionary. Since "1" comes before "2", any String starting with "1" will precede any other starting with "2".

You should use a custom comparator to implement [Natural Sorting](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/). A good example would be [Alphanum](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html), from Dave Koelle, which you would use like this:

```
Collections.sort(myarraylist, new AlphanumComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple class to order my `Strings`:

```
public abstract class StringOrderer {

    public static ArrayList<String> order(ArrayList<String> items, boolean ascending) {

        Collections.sort(items, new StringComparator());    

        // reverse the order
        if(!ascending) Collections.reverse(items);

        return items; 
    }

    class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

            // use the users default locale to sort the strings
            Collator c = Collator.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

            return c.compare(s1, s2);
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea is that i have a **custom** `Comparator` that uses the default `Locale`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using String in the Array list it alway checks characters. Better you try using Integer. It may works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As String can not be extended, it is better to change `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<ClassWithStringAttribute>` then implement Comparable in `ClassWithStringAttribute` when you need custom comparison. For your particular case and illustration, the following class should work, though not a nice approach.

```
myarraylist= StringSorter.getSortedList(myarraylist);
```

Will give you a sorted list

```
public class StringSorter implements Comparable<StringSorter>{

    String tempString;
    public StringSorter(String data) {
        this.tempString = data;
    }
    public static List<String> getSortedList(List<String> unsortedList){
        List<StringSorter> tempList=new ArrayList<StringSorter>();
        for (String current : unsortedList) {
            tempList.add(new StringSorter(current));
        }
        Collections.sort(tempList);
        List<String> sortedString=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (StringSorter current : tempList) {
            sortedString.add(current.tempString);
        }
        return  sortedString;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StringSorter other) {
        Integer otherInt=Integer.parseInt(other.tempString.replaceFirst("Item ", ""));
        Integer thisInt=Integer.parseInt(this.tempString.replaceFirst("Item ", ""));
        if(otherInt>thisInt){
            return -1;
        }else if(otherInt<thisInt){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is not necessary. You can provide a custom `Comparator` for `Collections.sort()`

Answer (score -1):

How about this custom `Comparator`,

```
public class StringNumSuffixComparator implements Comparator<String>{

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String str1 = o1;
        String str2 = o2;
        Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(str1.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
        Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(str2.replaceAll("\\D+",""));        
        return num2.compareTo(num1);
    }
}
```

To sort them with `Collections.sort()`,

```
Collections.sort(items, new StringNumSuffixComparator());
```